# Execute a string?

Tags: julia

I wanted to execute a string, but found that there's no `exec` function in Julia:

```
a = 1
println(exec("a")) # ERROR: exec not defined
```

Is there a way to execute a string in Julia?

The original problem is that I'm trying to log a list of variables:

```
thingsToLog = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

to file:

```
open(logFile, "w") do io
    for thing in thingsToLog
        write(io, @sprintf("%s = %s\n", thing, eval(thing)))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

As said above, you can call parse to create an AST from the string, and then call `eval` on that. In your example though, it seems easier to create your list as

```
thingsToLog = [:a, :b, :c]
```

to avoid having through `parse` at all. Usually, it's both easier and safer to pass quoted ASTs like this (in this case, symbols) directly to `eval`; you can also interpolate ASTs into quoted ASTs if it's not enough with a fixed set of ASTs (see the manual for more details).

A few more words of caution when it comes to `eval`:

- By design, it only works in global scope.
- It's not fast, since it needs to compile new code. So it's best reserved for evaluations that only need to be done once (such as evaluating generated method or type definitions), or when speed is not really important.
- It can make for pretty hard to understand code.

Regarding evaluation in local scope, reading this thread made me realize that most of the required functionality was already present in the `Debug` package, so I just released an update that allows this (the cautions above still apply though). The function where you want to evaluate code in local scope has to be wrapped with the `@debug_analyze` macro. Then you can retrieve an object representing the local scope using `@localscope`, and retrieve values of local variables from it by indexing with the corresponding symbols. Example:

```
using Debug
@debug_analyze function f(x,y,z,thingsToLog)
    s = @localscope
    for sym in thingsToLog
        println(sym, " = ", s[sym])
    end
end
f(1,2,3,[:x,:z])
```

which prints

```
x = 1
z = 3
```

For more details, see [this section](https://github.com/toivoh/Debug.jl#evaluation-of-code-in-local-scope) in the `Debug` package readme.

Comment: More interesting is how you might refactor a function `complicated_alg(a,b,c; thingsToLog=[:x, :y, :z]])` to work as expected since `eval` won't work in this context.

Comment: How about posting a new question for this, and flesh out the details a bit? It's not quite clear to me which scenario you have in mind.

Comment: It's just what I'm imagining @Adobe really wants to do: get optional debug output from a complicated algorithm by passing the names of the variables to print.  I agree that it's a different question, but I'm guessing this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Call `parse` on the string first, then pass the resulting AST to `eval`: `eval(parse("a"))`. Optionally you can pass a module to `eval` to have the expression be evaluated in a certain context (see [`eval`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.eval)).

Comment: `eval(Meta.parse("a"))` in Julia v1.0