# Populating a julia dictionary with an array of symbols

Tags: scope, metaprogramming, julia

I'm getting stuck on some basics of scope in Julia expressions.  Can someone help tell me what is going wrong inside the for loop below?  Inside the lopp the first expression works and the second does not, though both work with variables from the global scope.

```
x = 1

glob_obj = :x
eval(:(println($glob_obj)))
eval(:(println("$glob_obj")))
# Prints
# 1
# x

objs = [:x]
for obj = objs
    eval(:(println($obj)))
    eval(:(println("$obj")))
end
# Prints
# 1
# ERROR: obj not defined
#  in anonymous at no file:3
```

For context, I am ultimately interested in writing a Julia function that populates a dictionary from an array of symbols in a local scope, i.e., a function like

```
x = 1
y = "foo"
populate_dict([:x, :y]) # ...resulting in 
{ "x" => 1, "y" => "foo"}
```

Importantly, I'd like to be able to use this in any function and have it pick up variables from the local scope.  For even more context, this is to easily easily write JSON files with arbitrary lists of symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scoping issue that you are running into is that `eval` always evaluates expressions in global scope (the current module, unless specified otherwise). In this particular case, you could deal with that by using

```
println(obj)
```

instead of `eval(:(println("$obj")))`; there's no evaluation necessary to look at the symbol itself!

But if your ultimate goal is to pick up values of local variables in a function, the answer as indicated above is that `eval` doesn't do that. This is a pretty deep design decision that allows the compiler to do all sorts of optimizations that it wouldn't be able to otherwise.

It is however possible to get at local variables with the aid of the `Debug` package, see my answer to [Execute a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300126/execute-a-string/29303412).